# Are there characters who "survive" the reboot events?

Tags: dc

As far as I know, in the DC universe, at least three reboots have occurred. At first, there are infinite Earths. Then there are 52 universes. The old 52 becomes the new 52. It seems recently, after the Metal event, reality is being reshaped again.

After each reboot event, old stories are "erased" and almost all characters are replaced by new versions, if not eliminated. However, I wonder if there are any characters that survived the reboot event. I mean, are there any characters

1. do not die in the reboot event;
2. and are not be replaced by a new version;
3. and retain their memory of the stories and events before the reboot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off the top of my head, Earth-1 Psycho Pirate retained all his memories for before/during Crisis on Infinite Earths. (COIE #12)

(COIE also ended with Earth-Prime Superboy, Earth-3 Alexander Luthor, and Earth-2 Superman and Lois Lane escaping to a pocket dimension, but since they didn't appear again until Infinite Crisis, 20 years later, I'm not sure that counts!)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to cite the specific issues that show what you've described here. If you could also add relevant quotes or images, that'd be even better.